# Fatal Error C1509 "Too many exception handler states in function"

Tags: c++, try-catch

So I'm working with some auto-generated code that's trying to initialize about 4k variables inside a try-catch block in a constructor.

The problem is the auto-generator is only aware of one variable at a time. My solutions have been:

- To roll each variable declaration into a try catch block
- To create a static initializer function that will initialize the variables and just call this static function from the constructor's try catch block

The massive number of try catch blocks have a pretty big impact on performance. But the static initializer gets really messy with how many variables are passed in.

Is there a third solution that I'm missing? Or is the static initializer my best bet?

Comment: If the code is auto-generated, then perhaps you can wrap a set of variables in one try-catch-block. Or break the whole function into smaller functions, or something like that... The error message certainly sounds like a "compiler limitation" - you may of course be able to work around it by using a different compiler too...

Comment: So that's what I feel would be the best too, but I'm unable to with the current generator design, cause I only know about one variable at a time during generation.